# One way traffic PPTPD Server / No Internet Access

Tags: linux, networking, debian, vpn, pptpd

I just set up a pptp server on Debian Linux yesterday by following this guide: http://poptop.sourceforge.net/dox/debian-howto.phtml  When I tried to connect to the server using both XP and iOS, the client successfully connects to the PPTP server, however, I can't seem to access the Internet thru the pptp connection. When I tried to capture traffic using tcpdump on just the pptp interface itself, I can see only outgoing traffic and no incoming traffic at all. (Please see image)

[image: Wireshark Capture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

more than likely, your internet gateway (router?) does not have a route back to your PPTP gateway.  So when a packet comes from x.x.x.x (VPN ip-range) the router throws it to the WAN interface instead of back to the PPTP server.

Comment: Actually both the client and the pptp server are located in the same network. I was able to fix the one way issue. However, I forwarded port 1723 on my router but I can't connect to the pptp server from the internet. Any advice?

Comment: PPTP requires a lot more than just port 1723.   You must allow GRE traffic... as well. (GRE is a Protocol... not a port)

Comment: I never get how to allow gre traffic. I have a Linksys wireless router and the only option I see is VPN pptp passthru and that's enabled.